# Calling tap_example.py from C# to get Membase TAP Stream

Tags: c#, python, dynamic, ironpython, membase

I am trying to use the dynamic language run time / IronPython to simply run a .py script with command arguments and then get the std output. This is for executing the membase TAP protocol which isn't implemented in C# yet:

```
public class MembaseTap
{
    public void Tap()
    {
        var pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine(); 

        pyEngine.ExecuteFile(@"E:\Program Files\Membase\Server\bin\tap_example.py"); 


    }
}
```

I am able to use ExecuteFile to run the script, I believe, but I do not know how one would pass in arguments in this scenario if possible.

Essentially if I were running the command from the command line it would be:

```
python tap_example.py localhost:11210
```

I could simply run this from C# but that would require Python installed. That is one fall back option, but I'd prefer to use the DLR.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the arguments when you create the engine as shown by Jeff Hardy's answer in the [Script arguments and Embedded IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601364/script-arguments-and-embedded-ironpython) post on StackOverflow. Your C# code would look like the following:

```
public class MembaseTap
{
    public void Tap()
    {
        var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        options["Arguments"] = new [] { "foo", "bar" };
        var pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine(options); 

        pyEngine.ExecuteFile(@"E:\Program Files\Membase\Server\bin\tap_example.py"); 
    }
}
```

To redirect the standard output you can use methods on the pyEngine.Runtime.IO object as shown in  [How can I redirect the stdout of ironpython in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055002/how-can-i-redirect-the-stdout-of-ironpython-in-c).