# Passing command line parameters to IronPython from C# application?

Tags: c#, ironpython

How do I pass command line parameters from my C# application to IronPython 2.x?  Google is only returning results about how to do it with Iron Python 1.x.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScriptRuntime scriptRuntime = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
    // Pass in script file to execute but how to pass in other arguments in args?
    ScriptScope scope = scriptRuntime.ExecuteFile(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: And 1.x solution doesn't work in 2.x?

Comment: 1.x uses scriptEngine.Sys.argv which was removed in 2.x sadly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set the sys.argv via the following C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var scriptRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
    var argv = new List();
    args.ToList().ForEach(a => argv.Add(a));
    scriptRuntime.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
    scriptRuntime.ExecuteFile(args[0]);
}
```

having the following python script

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

and calling the exe like

```
Test.exe SomeScript.py foo bar
```

gives you the output

```
SomeScript.py
foo
bar
```

**Another option** would be passing the prepared options to `Python.CreateRuntime` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602006/468244)