# Run Python script from C# with command line params

Tags: c#, ironpython

I need to execute Python script from C# using IronPython and pass into it some command line parameters.
Is there any way to do it?

My sample code:

```
        var e = Python.CreateEngine();
        var source = e.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"...");
        source.Execute();
```

Comment: please go see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1602006/468244

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  When you create your engine, call the overload that takes in additional options and set the `"Arguments"` to your array of strings.

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Arguments", new[] { "foo", "bar", "biz baz" } },
};
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
var script = @"
import sys
print sys.argv # ['foo', 'bar', 'biz baz']
";
engine.Execute(script);
```