# IronPython how to pass command line arguments to a script file from within C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

IronPython will run directly from C# without `Process.Start`

The script file I want to load requires one parameter (`filename`),
how do you write that out in C#?

> Note: This will hopefully be a a conversion of a Python script to a Windows GUI application where you use the GUI to choose the file.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. You want to run IronPython from inside C# and pass it a parameter?

Comment: If speed isn't a major issue, why not write the params to a file with c#, close the file, then let your python script read the paras from the same file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script arguments and Embedded IronPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601364/script-arguments-and-embedded-ironpython)

Comment: i have a project setup with iron python now i need to run a scriptfile an give it a argument "generator.py /somefile.dat"

Comment: this is not a duplicate of that what ever they wrote out. it dose not even come close to being able to compile...my question is broader in scope and im not asking to embed anything. i want to run a py script with command line parameter  the py script is proprietary and im not allowed to change if i redistribute it

Comment: Then what are you trying to say with "within C#"? I assumed that you are talking about IronPython.Hosting, instantiating and Engine/Scope and executing the script file. The Q/A I linked talks about embedded IronPython in terms of embedded/hosted engine. That does not necessarily imply embedded script source.

Comment: using the c sharp language using iron python

Comment: I still stand by this being a duplicate. You would just have to change the answer to `options["Arguments"] = new [] { "generator.py", "/somefile.dat" };`.

Comment: that dose not come close answer my question thats a vague snippet of code. the code you referenced is far from proper and every line of it throws errors

Comment: its clear you do not know the answer or you would have done so by answering it

Comment: I am not usually one to let someone bully me into answering but I am curious if my wild assumptions and speculations of what you are trying to do were correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a script `generator.py` that could look like

```py
import sys
fileName = sys.argv[0]
print "working on", fileName
```

an IronPython engine can be hosted in C#/.NET by

```cs
var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Arguments"] = new[] { @"/somefile.dat" };

var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
var runtime = engine.Runtime;
var scope = engine.CreateScope();

var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"generator.py");
script.Execute(scope);
```

which results in the output `working on /somefile.dat`.